# package-lock.json file, package with "optional": true

Tags: node.js, npm

One of my work mate's PRs contains a package-lock.json update, which added `"optional": true`:

```
 "minimist": {
   "version": "0.0.8",
   "bundled": true,
-  "dev": true
+  "dev": true,
+  "optional": true
 },
 "minipass": {
```

I am not sure what this means even after googling around. Could someone please explain?

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 74):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json#optional:

> If true then this dependency is either an optional dependency ONLY of the top level module or a transitive dependency of one. This is false for dependencies that are both an optional dependency of the top level and a transitive dependency of a non-optional dependency of the top level.

It's safe to merge this change.

The reason you see this change is most likely because [npm slightly changed how package-lock.json is structured in version 6.6](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/76). Your mate basically ran `npm install` with npm 6.6+ on a package-lock.json previously generated with npm 6.5-.

You should be able to avoid this kind of issue by making sure everyone on your team uses a recent version of `npm`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me this is something that's gone away with npm 6.6+

Answer (score 9):

After a package is removed from dependencies, its dependencies are marked `"optional": true` in `package-lock.json`.

It is usually safe to remove such packages either by hand or by

```
$ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules/
$ npm install
```

However, this is not 100% safe, as some packages will be updated to newer versions.

Comment: Ref your: *"not 100% safe, as some packages will be updated to newer versions"*. The whole point of having a package manager is to be able to clone, install and have a working system. The same working system across the board. If your project depends on some packages having an older version, just because `npm i` hasn't been run recently, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @tao considering how frequently upstream packages get released with bugs and that some of them disregard SemVer, I subscribe to the opinion that running `npm i` is not 100% safe.

Comment: @villasv the point of using node is so you could have continuous integration. Which means: *"you deploy your project on a server, run `npm i` and it works"*. If your build depends on changes you have made to your packages after `npm i`, you're pretty much developing as in the late 80's: you need to upload the exact copy from local machine onto the server in order for it to work. In which case you shouldn't bother using node at all. You can simply place all required vendor assets in a folder and load them from there.

Comment: Nowhere on the CI methodology there's an assumption that you should be running `npm i`. In fact, npm maintainers even gifted us with an actually safe alternative: `npm ci` which, as de docs mention, is made for CI environments. Now, you can dispute if you think if that's ideal or not, but that's something you're going to have to discuss with the NPM team itself.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't know what you mean by *"100% safe"*. You probably refer to having versions in your `packages.json` set as `^x.y.z`. You can always use `~x.y.z` for any packages you fear might introduce breaking changes in minor upgrades. Or on all of them, if you don't trust any. And that ***is*** 100% safe. You'll always get the same result, regardless of latest stable on that major.

Comment: Ref: *"nowhere on the CI methodology there's an assumption you should be running `npm i`"*. [Automate the build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Automate_the_build).

Comment: Assuming that even patch version of libraries that are *not under your control* are always 100% safe and compatible is naive and will eventually break your site.  Upstream developers are human, they make mistakes.  Every upgrade, no matter how minor, must be tested.  Blindly running `npm i`, unless you have pinned all your dependencies down to a specific version, is never a good idea.  Hopefully you have testing in your CI pipeline to catch any issues that may arise before this reaches production at least.

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons would be:

Some npm packages might require dependent packages(Eg minimist) to work in different OS. NPM marks this packages as optional on npm install, if at all, it is not required depending on OS you are using.

Please check the below issue:

Open Issue: package-lock.json and optional packages : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17722

Hope it helps.